How to Extract Digital Signatures from a PDF Using Node.js?
I'm trying to extract information about all the digital signatures in a PDF file using Node.js. I found a way to obtain some data that appears to contain this information, but it seems to be jumbled.
Here is my current code:
const forge = require("node-forge");
const fs = require("fs");
const { Buffer } = require("buffer");


function GetSignaturesByteRange(FileBuffer) {

    const ByteRangeList = [];

    let ByteRangeStart = 0;

    while ((ByteRangeStart = FileBuffer.indexOf("/ByteRange [", ByteRangeStart)) !== -1) {

        const ByteRangeEnd = FileBuffer.indexOf("]", ByteRangeStart);
        const ByteRange = FileBuffer.slice(ByteRangeStart, ByteRangeEnd + 1).toString();

        const ByteRangeString = /(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+)/.exec(ByteRange);
        const ByteRangeArray = ByteRangeString.slice(1, 5).map(Number); // Convert to integers

        // Add the ByteRange to the list
        ByteRangeList.push(ByteRangeArray);

        // Move past the current ByteRange
        ByteRangeStart = ByteRangeEnd + 1;

    }

    return ByteRangeList;
}

function GetSignatureData(FileBuffer, ByteRange) {

    // Extract the specified range from the buffer
    let ByteRangeBuffer = FileBuffer.slice(ByteRange[1] + 1, ByteRange[2] - 1)

    // Remove the zeroes from the end of the buffer
    let EndIndex = ByteRangeBuffer.length;
    while (EndIndex > 0 && ByteRangeBuffer[EndIndex - 1] === 0x30) {
        EndIndex--;
    }

    ByteRangeBuffer = ByteRangeBuffer.slice(0, EndIndex);

    return ByteRangeBuffer.toString("binary");
}

const InputFile = fs.readFileSync("./signed.pdf");
const AllByteRanges = GetSignaturesByteRange(InputFile);

let SignatureBuffer = GetSignatureData(InputFile, AllByteRanges[0]);


console.log(SignatureBuffer);

fs.writeFileSync("Sigature.bin", Buffer.from(SignatureBuffer, "hex"));

The Signature.bin file produced by this code contains some data such as my name and city from when I digitally signed the PDF, but it is surrounded by what seems to be garbage data.
How can I properly extract and clean up the digital signature information from the PDF? Any advice or improvements to my code would be greatly appreciated!

The signature bytes you extract have the format of a CMS signature container. Read it accordingly.

I used the code from the broken npm package ninja-labs/verify-pdf and modified it to retrieve the data the code can be found on my github here
